# show that the number of standard tableau of shape $(n^2)$ is the Catalan number

Tags: catalan-numbers, young-tableaux

How would one show that the number of standard tableau of shape $(n^2)$ is the Catalan number

$\mathrm{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$2n\choose{n}$

any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to assume that by shape $(n^2)$ you mean $2\times n$ tableaux, as the result is not true for $n\times n$ tableaux. First verify that there is a bijection between standard tableaux of this shape and [Dyck paths](https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gabriella_Baracchini_final_paper.pdf) [PDF] of length $2n$: the numbers in the first row of the tableau are the positions of the up-steps in the Dyck path, and the numbers in the second row are the positions of the down-steps. Then use or prove the [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Fifth_proof) that the number of Dyck paths (or Dyck words, or balanced parenthesis strings) of length $2n$ is $C_n$.

You can also use the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) to get the result.